# How can I get all windows to open in the middle of the screen at a predefined size?

Tags: windows-7

I'm running windows 7, 64 bit.

I have a very large monitor and it's tiring on the eyes to have to look on such a wide screen for tasks that only require about a 15.6 laptop screen definition.

I would like all program windows to open at X size in the middle of the screen at a specific size, smack in the middle, in my line of vision and ignore the wide screen. Can do this manually of course but repetitive and annoying, is there a way to do that?

[image: Windows open in middle of screen]

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you might use the Autohotkey to automate that task on specific events

[Autohotkey Winmove](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm)

Comment: For ALL windows, ALL the time? That wouldn't work, I need a solution that works for everything, almost like cutting the screen to size with a hacksaw! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following will surely do your job
 
[MaxMax - mthings.net](http://mthings.net/download.php?lang=ang)

Steps:-

1. Download and install as usual
2. Launch MaxMax
3. From taskbar right click on its icon and select configure
4. Set the limits for all four sides and click ok
5. Try to change the sizes of active windows

There are other configurations too so you might check them out

Do report back and accept the answer if it solves problem